# How is util.Collections used

Tags: java, collections

I don't understand how Collections is generally used. The confusion started when I found out what binary search was and I looked up an implementation in java. The first I found was this https://www.javatpoint.com/binary-search-in-java, but I also found this on Geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-binarysearch-java-examples/.

They pretty much have the same output and obviously the second is simpler, but I don't really understand what the point is of the first link. To generalize for all of Collections, are there situations where using Collections is disadvantageous?

I'm sorry my question can't be more specific or if the question doesn't make sense, but I don't understand enough to make it more specific.

Comment: It's to prevent re-inventing the wheel, and using a built in library instead of re-writing a binary search saves time, as well as prevent mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a library class containing **util**ity methods for dealing with [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) types. That is, it has helpful methods which solve common problems or do useful things, so that you don't have to write your own code to do them.
Your first link shows an implementation of the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) from scratch, while your second link shows how to use the utility method `Collections.binarySearch`, which saves writing your own implementation.

The first link may be useful for educational purposes (since students often have to learn about the binary search algorithm), or it may be useful for people who need to adapt binary search to a different problem. For example, a variation of binary search can be used to find the *first* occurrence of the target number, or the smallest number greater than or equal to the target, but the `Collections.binarySearch` method cannot do either of these things, so you could have to write an implementation yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The first link you posted actually explains how a binary search works, giving the theory behind it, and how to implement it on your own.  This is good to understand how, and why a binary search works.

However, the Java language has a util library for Collections (Maps, Lists, etc) that have some of these simple methods already implemented.  The second link explains how to use that library.